# Why am I getting an infinite loop while trying to search my Binary Tree?

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

I inserted numbers into the tree. I use get to see if that number exists(knowing it does) and google chrome crashes because its looping infinitely. I've gone over the code multiple times and I can't figure out why its not working. Please help.

My commands in console:

```
 tree = new BinaryTree;

 tree.insert(15);
 tree.insert(23);
 tree.insert(6);
```

etc...

```
 tree.get(55);
```

***Google Chrome CRASHES*** NOOOOOO *collapses*

```
class Node {
    constructor(val){
        this.val = val;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree {
    constructor(){
        this.root = null;
    }

    insert(val){
        var newNode = new Node(val);
        if (this.root){
            var current = this.root
            while(true) {
            if(val < current.val){
                if(current.left === null){
                    current.left = newNode;
                    return current;
                }
                current = current.left;
            }
            if(val > current.val){
                if(current.right === null){
                    current.right = newNode;
                    return current; 
                }
                current = current.right;
            }
            if(val === current.val){
                return "already exists";
            }
        }
    }
    this.root = newNode;
    return this;
}

    get(val) {

        if(this.root){
            var current = this.root;
            while(true){
                if (val < current.val){
                    if(current.left == null){
                        return "does not exist";
                    }
                    current = current.left;
                }
                if (val > current.val){
                    if(current.right == null){
                        return "does not exist";
                    }
                    current = current.right;
                }
                 if(current === val){
                        return current;
               } 
            }
        }
        return "tree is empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps the way you add the Nodes is wrong

Comment: No it works fine. I insert a ton of values and checked and made sure they were in all the right places.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] where you show how a small example tree is constructed and how you are calling the method.

Comment: a) you are searching for a value that is neither `>`, `<` nor `===`, e.g. `NaN` or `undefined` b) you have created a cyclic graph, not a tree

Comment: @Mugs - well the code you posted doesn't look like it should go infinitely - have you tried debugging it to see if some nodes are visited more than once?

Comment: are you sure ```current``` has all the properties you think it has?

Comment: Much simpler: `var current = this.root; while (current != null) { if (val<current.val) current=current.left else if (val>current.val) current=current.right else return current } throw new Error("not found")`

Comment: Go step by step in the debugger, and you can see where it goes wrong.

Comment: @Mugs the example you posted works fine for me, it returns `"Does not exist"` for `tree.get(55)`.

Comment: @Bergi Okay I updated it, and it should return "does not exist" if the value isn't in the tree. I haven't studied graphs yet but i'm pretty sure its a tree. Each node has two children, one left one right.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the code! i'll be sure to study it.

Comment: @some Okay, good idea. I haven't figured out how to work it yet. Guess now is a good time. I'll stop being lazy

Comment: @Bergi oh really!? maybe its google chromes snippet then. I'm doing all my coding in the browser in snippets. I'm finding out it can be pretty glitchy. Thanks!

Comment: `if (current.val === val)` .. not `if (current === val)`

Comment: @JaromandaX I have mentally, but Ill learn how to use the debugger so I can be more sure of myself

Comment: see how you test `if (val < current.val)` and `if (val > current.val)` and in `insert` you test `if(val === current.val)` ... but in `get`, you suddenly test `if(current === val)`

Comment: @JaromandaX Omg thank you so much. I'm blind. I guess i'm way too tired right now.

Comment: all good, I didn't see it until you posted the `insert` code

Comment: This is a good example of how the name of the variable can help. If ´current´ had a name like `node` or `currentNode` it would probably have been easier to spot the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, you are simple doing the equality check wrong at the bottom of the get() method. You are checking the node object itself for equality to the passed in value instead of it's .val property.

You wrote:

```
if(current === val){
    return current;
}
```

When it needs to be:

```
if(current.val === val){
    return current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code never breaks out of this while loop

```
 while(true) {
   if(val < current.val){
      if(current.left === null){
         current.left = newNode;
         return current;
       }
      current = current.left;
   }
 }
```

`white(true)` will always be true, so that runs infinitely if you don't return out of the loop, so my guess is that for some reason
`current.left === null`
is never true

Comment: There are return statements in the if statements, and the if statements cover all the possible values of (val) so it runs until the tree finds a null or it finds its value.

Comment: perhaps i should edit my answer. My suspicion is that it never returns out of the loop. Looking at your code i don't see anything else that will cause an infinite loop

Comment: Oh no worries, yeah someone found that I had if(current === val) instead of if(current.val === val). So I was comparing the input to a node :,( which would never be true lol. So for all inputs which have a corresponding value in the tree it will loop infinitely and never end like you said